# My washing machine drain is over flowing.

Tags: plumbing, washer, laundry

So my laundry room looks like a river. When the washer drains water is coming up from the hole in the floor where the drain pipe leads into. If the drain was backed up it should come out where the washer hose meets the pvc pipe correct? Well my land lord is a Crack head. And said he fixed it. But now it's 10 times worse. I can't even find the drain in the basement underneath so I have no clue where the drain pipe even leads. Any direction would be wonderful.

Comment: Is that "hole in the floor" a floor drain by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

There is a plug below the floor drain. This is why when the washer drains it backs up. Soon it will start backing up when you take a bath.
The reason it got worse is the land lord knocked more debris into the plug and it is draining even more slowly.
A long power snake is the best way to clean these problems as it will get worse with time, drain cleaner may help but I wouldn’t count on it. (I say it will start backing up with a bath, this depends if the bath is on the right side of the plug).

Comment: Power augers are available for rent relatively cheaply. There may be two sizes available. I'd go with the smaller one here. Tell the store that you need to clean 1-1/2" and 2" pipe.

Comment: I wouldn't try a DIY fix if I were the original poster -- he referenced a landlord, so he doesn't own the property... thus he'll be responsible for any damage (even if he just breaks through a pipe that's already corroded and weakened). If the landlord is unable or unwilling to fix it, I'd call a plumber to do it, so if anything breaks, the plumber can either prove that it wasn't his fault, or fix the damage himself. Then the tenant can try to get the landlord to pay for the plumber's fees.

Comment: Don't loose the power auger head in the pipe!  Another reason to follow @Johnny advice.